# Angular 4 error "Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a code that I want to upload files

```
  uploadImages(fda){
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+"/uploadImages/"+fda)
  .map((res : Response) => res);
}
```

but shows the error of

```
ERROR in E:/MCQ/CsExamsModule - Client/src/app/services/question.service.ts (90,14): Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.
```

Comment: You are not passing the image content to the server through second parameter of `post ` function.

Comment: you pass only one variable but the function takes more then 1 `post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : Observable<Response> `

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `{}` as the second argument, like this:

```
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+"/uploadImages/"+fda, {})
```

Comment: Not sure if there are any downsides to this but it worked a treat, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to track the reason of this kind of the error, if it is thrown by the pipe (as when you are drilling only into your custom pipe filter definition with the desired number of args, you will never thing that the compiler prefers to deal with another one already exited with another agrs). For me it was just coinciding with another already imported pipe having another number of args. And I have figured this out only being forced to change the name of my custom pipe method, as then I was finally drilled in my IDE to the initial preexisted pipe defined with the same name.